# Why Intent is not redirect on calling Activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview, android-activity

I have ListView contains two TextViews(say t1,t2) and that ListView is created by xml, which is inflate in the Activity. 
My requirment is, that if the user clicks on a ListView item, which contains t1 a new Activity should and when clicking on an item, which contains t2 start another Activity. 
But problem is, that it is not working when I am clicking at any of ListView items, it moves to same Activity in both case.

My code (as -  inside getView() method):

```
mylayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    if (listType == 1) {
                        Log.v("active", "On Click " + (position));
                        Intent intent = new Intent(VoucherActiveScreen.this,MyVoucherDetailPage.class);
                        intent.putExtra("selectedIndex", position);
                        intent.putExtra("listType", listType);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    else if (listType == 3) {
                                 //String str = offerPrice.getText().toString();
                                 //System.out.println(str);
                                 if (voucherOffer.getIs_redeem().toString().equals("1"))
                                 {
                                    System.out.println(voucherOffer.getIs_redeem().toString()+"if Rate"); //its working when click listview which contains Rate

                                    Intent  intratedeal=new Intent(getBaseContext(),RateDeal.class);
                                    intratedeal.setClass(getBaseContext(), RateDeal.class);
                                    startActivityForResult(intratedeal, 1);
                                 }
                                 else
                                     {
                                     System.out.println(voucherOffer.getIs_redeem().toString()+"else View"); //its working when click listview which contains View
                                     Intent  intratevendor=new Intent(getBaseContext(),RateVendor.class);
                                     //intratevendor.setClass(getBaseContext(), RateVendor.class);
                                        startActivityForResult(intratevendor, 1);
                                     }
                             /*Intent intent = new Intent(
                                        VoucherActiveScreen.this,
                                        MyVoucherDetailPage.class);
                                intent.putExtra("listType", listType);
                                intent.putExtra("selectedIndex", position);*/
                                Log.v("inactiveeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee", "On Click " + (position));

                                //startActivity(intent); 

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }
            }
        });
```

please any one help...
  control is going right if-else block but intent is not redirecting same Activity

Comment: Are you getting any error or Exception?? Please write that error here...

Comment: There is no error,problem is that not redirect Required Activity mentioned in the if-else block,while detect right block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setFlags in your intent like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(VoucherActiveScreen.this,MyVoucherDetailPage.class);
intent.putExtra("selectedIndex", position);
intent.putExtra("listType", listType);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

The snippet above will start a new activity task. See this link:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK